# Strange AV during DLL call

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have created a sample project in D7 demonstrating that strange issue. It is here:
http://speedy.sh/n9Etr/OpenCV-BugTest.zip

I have a procedure which looks like that:

```
function Rec (image: PIplImage): String;
begin
  DLL_CALL;
end;
```

When I call Rec, I get AV on DLL_CALL, but ...
If I Add Second parameter to the function:

```
function Rec (image: PIplImage; Something: String): String;
begin
  DLL_CALL;
end;
```

Then DLL_CALL succeed.

Variable: 'Something' is irrelevant and is not taken anywhere ...

Really, I don't know what is happening ...

### EDIT:

I use cvSaveImage of openCV library.

```
function cvSaveImage(const filename: PAnsiChar; const image: pointer): integer; 
    cdecl; external CV_HIGH_GUI_DLL;
```

All my methods are exported with cdecl param's call convention.

The complete procedure is:

```
function TCVR.Rec(image: PIplImage): String;
const
  THRESH = 50;
var
  imgDisorted: PIplImage;
  Storage: PCvMemStorage;
  Squares: PCvSeq;

begin
  imgDisorted := nil;
  result := '';

  Storage := cvCreateMemStorage(0);

  cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(0, 0, image^.width and -2, image^.height and -2));
  PyrDownUp(image);
  cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(0, 0, image^.width and -2, image^.height and -2));

  imgDisorted := cvCreateImage(cvSize(image^.width and -2, image^.height and -2), 8, 1);
  cvSaveImage('c:\test.jpg', image); <--- AV here only when I have 1 parameter in my Rec.
end;
```

Comment: if you want an answer, show full details of the DLL and your call to it. You are probably mixing up calling conventions.

Comment: What happens when you strip out everything but the call to cvSaveImage?

Comment: if there is only cvSaveImage('c:\test.jpg', image); then it works ok. I have also noticed that cvSaveImnage after cvCreateImage causes AV, before: cvCreateImage is ok.

Comment: In fact, where did you get `image` from? How did you create it in the first place? Which opencv function did you call to create it?

Comment: There is: img := cvLoadImage(PChar(fileName), 0); and call to: Rec(img);

Comment: @David Heffernan I have included a sample project in D7 demonstrating that issue. Link is available at the top of the post. Thanks

Comment: I found interesting thing. If I release the imgDistorted variable in Rec method (cvReleaseImage (imgDisorted);) then that error is not raised. Also If i switch off in project settings for debugger: Optimization option then my above code snippet works like a charm. I think there is someting out there with the pointers management on the opencv part ...

Comment: Check import declarations of your dll. Probably interface of this dll has changed, but your code doesn't reflect them.

Comment: @John, I downloaded your test app and load it with D7 with 7.1 Update patch. If run the compiled Project1.exe without rebuilding it, AV error occured, as described by you. But if I rebuilding it (without changing anything), the program run without AV, and the testOut.jpg file produced.

Comment: @Torbins You were right, cvSaveImage declaraion has changed .. fixing number of parameters did the job. Please write it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using 1.0 function definitions with a 2.4.1 DLL version. The function definitions changed, so you're nearly three years out of date. In particular, [`cvSaveImage` expects three parameters](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvsaveimage#imwrite), not just two. An excerpt from [the 2.0 release](http://opencvlibrary.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opencvlibrary/tags/2.0/opencv/include/opencv/highgui.h?revision=2218&view=markup#l210):

```
CVAPI(int) cvSaveImage( const char* filename, const CvArr* image,
                        const int* params CV_DEFAULT(0) );
```

Update your DLL import unit to match the DLL you're using (or switch to an older version of the library). I'd translate that function to Delphi like this:

```
function cvSaveImage(filename: PAnsiChar; image: PCvArr; params: PInteger = nil); cdecl;
```

---

Here's why you get the particular failure you saw:

The DLL doesn't know that you're only passing two parameters, so it reads from what it believes to be the third parameter and interprets it as a pointer to an array of integers. Whatever's really there probably isn't a pointer at all, and so you get an access violation.

Adding another parameter to your `Rec` function causes it to have four parameters (`Self`, `image`, `Something`, and `Result`), which forces one of the parameters onto the stack. Since the stack is a little bigger, the DLL ends up reading from a different location. That location probably holds a null pointer, so the DLL doesn't try to read any array elements, and so the code works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Check import declarations of your dll. Probably interface of this dll has changed, but your code doesn't reflect that.